# Very difficult integral (for me)

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Could someone point me to an online resource where I can look up

$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos(\vec k\cdot\vec x)}{\sqrt{|\vec k|^2+m^2}}\,dk_1\,dk_2\,dk_3$$

where $\vec k$ and $\vec x$ are 3-vectors, and $m$ is a constant.  Also, if you know how to do it step by step and want to show off your fancy integration, that would also be very helpful.  Thanks ;)

Comment: What is the region of integration?

Comment: Perhaps try [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/calculators/integral-calculator/)

Comment: @zhw. This is an indefinite integral, but all of k-space should suffice, meaning $k^i\in\{-\infty,\infty\}$

Comment: This integral over all space does not converge as given, but it can be given meaning as a 3D Fourier transform. If you search for that your should be able to find more information, this is a fairly common integral in physics.

Comment: What's the square of a vector?

Comment: @RhysHughes Thanks, I tried "integrate  dx dy dz cos(ax+by+cz)/(sqrt(x^2+y^2+z^2+d^2))" with the differentials before and after the expression.  Do I need to tell it what a,b,c,d are?  Not familiar with Wolfram syntax.  Thanks

Comment: @MarkViola Hi Mark, that is actually a great answer for me.  Can you tell me you got it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The integral diverges, but can be interpreted in terms of tempered distributions.  We proceed using formal manipulations.

Rotate the coordinate system of that the polar axis aligns with $\vec x$.  Denote $|\vec k|$ by $k$ and $|\vec x|$ by $x$.  Then, we can write (in distribution)

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos(\vec k\cdot\vec x)}{\sqrt{|\vec k|^2+m^2}}\,dk_1\,dk_2\,dk_3&=2\pi \int_0^\infty  \int_0^\pi\frac{\cos (kx\cos(\theta))}{\sqrt{k^2+m^2}}\,k^2 \sin(\theta)\,d\theta\,dk\\\\
&=\frac{4\pi}x \int_0^\infty \frac{k\sin(kx)}{\sqrt{k^2+m^2}}\,dk\\\\
&=-\frac{4\pi}x \frac{d}{dx}\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(kx)}{\sqrt{k^2+m^2}}\,dk\\\\
&=-\frac{4\pi}x \frac{dK_0(|m|x)}{dx}\\\\
&=\frac{4\pi |m| K_1(|m| x)}{x}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Can you tell me what $d^3\vec k$ means?

Comment: Very nice Mark, thanks.  I follow what you did until you wrote $K_0$.  What are the $K_n$?

Comment: Those are modified Bessel Functions of the second kind and orders $0$ and $1$.

Comment: @zhw. $d^3 \vec k$ is a shorthand notation for $dk_1\,dk_2\,dk_3$.  I've removed that vector arrow since that is likely the reason for your questioning the notation.

Comment: @MarkViola I am very glad that you showed me how to do this so concisely :-)

Comment: Pleased to hear.

Comment: Excuse me again give you a new score.

Answer (score 1):

There is no closed form for the (triple) antiderivative of this function. When taken over all space, this integral does not converge but may be taken as the Fourier transform of $1/\sqrt {k^2+m^2} $. This gives the position space free scalar field propagator, which is given in terms of special functions [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagator). (Under Feynman propagator.)

The integral may be computed by converting it to a four dimensional integral (as the one given on that page is), then applying contour integration and special function techniques. This process is rather involved, however.

Edit: or apply Mark Viola's much more straightforward technique, which I had not seen before :)